# Converter strings em CamelCase para kebab-case

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Tenho uma lista de botões...

```
<button @click="chamaEstilo($event)" :data-el="index" class="buttonEstilo" v-for="(item, index) in filteredList" :key="index" v-if="verificaRestricao(item)" >
    {{index}}
</button>
```

Gostaria que imprimisse o `{{index}}` no padrão de formatação das tags HTML para componentes, ou seja, se envio uma string com o valor **fontSize** deveria imprimir **font-size** e assim para todas as ocorrência de maíusculas...

Comment: Index imprime propriedades css, algumas com o nome em camelCasel, exemplo, (borderLeft, fontSize) queria imprimir elas normalmente (border-left, font-size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o que queres é converter strings em *CamelCase* para *kebab-case*,

podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function camelCaseToKebabCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase()
}

const testes = ['fooBar', 'kebab-case', 'fontSize'];
console.log(testes.map(camelCaseToKebabCase));

/* resultado:
[
  "foo-bar",
  "kebab-case",
  "font-size"
]
*/
```

e usar um filter para isso no Vue e no template ficaria:

```
<button @click="chamaEstilo($event)" :data-el="index" class="buttonEstilo" v-for="(item, index) in filteredList" :key="index" v-if="verificaRestricao(item)" >
    {{index | camelCaseToKebabCase}}
</button>
```